# HTTP ERROR :403, Python with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, http, urllib, http-error

Here is the code:

```
quote_page = "https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/fun/" + months [date.month].lower() + "/" + str(date.day)
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
event_box = soup.find('article', attrs={"class" : "fixed"})
event_box = event_box.find('h3')
event = event_box.text.strip()
print event
```

When I check my variable:

```
quote_page = https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/fun/june/8
```

I've tried printing quote_page and the link works fine in my browser,
but when I run the code and print "event" I get this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 252, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: ok
exit status 1
```

I think I remember that it worked earlier today but stopped when I tried again later.

Can anyone help?
(I'm fairly new to coding)

Comment: As the stack trace clearly explains, you have an error in `urllib2.urlopen`. Anything after the second line of your script is not executed. Check what HTTP Error 403 means. (Hint: You must have been forbidden from using that URL.)

Comment: can I do anything to get "unforbidden"? And can it have something to do with that I have tested it too many time in a period of time?

Comment: You have been probably blacklisted for too many frequent accesses. Give it a break and try another day. If it still does not work, try contacting the site administration. If they do not cooperate, you are pretty much doomed.